# OxyPlot trigger LineSeries color change notification

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter, oxyplot

I have an oxyplot, and a listbox with ColorPickers to select the LineSeries colors.

- The ColorPickers are bound to the LineSeries through a value converter (I could not use the oxyplot default color converter, because the ColorPickers use nullable Color-s, so I had to "customize" the OxyPlot.Wpf.OxyColorConverter)
- The color binding works in both directions: if I change the color in the ColorPickers, first the ConvertBack and then the Convert function is called. The LineSeries color and the ColorPicker colors are set.
- At startup, I add the LineSeries to the PlotModel.Series (see below)
- After that, before the first DataPoints would be added, the ColorConverter.Convert function is called, with a value = {A:0, B:1, G:0, R:0}. This sets the ColorPicker colors to some kind of transparent (the LineSeries colors do not change)

I guess, the problem is, that the LineSeries that are added to the PlotModel.Series do not have a valid color set, before I add DataPoints to them.

- I did not find any RaisePropertyChanged or similar notifications on the Series or LineSeries instances.
- I tried to call RaisePropertyChanged("PlotModel"); after the first datapoint - does not help nor with any combination of "PlotModel.Series.Color"
- The PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true); is called after each data point, but this does not notify the ColorPickers of color change.

So the question is: how can I make the ColorPickers take up the valid colors of the LineSeries after startup, before the ColorPickers are manually changed?

I would like to avoid setting the colors manually at instantiation, right now I'm happy with the colors the PlotModel assigns to them.

OxyPlot and ListBox:

```
<oxy:PlotView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="plot1" Model="{Binding PlotModel}"/>
...
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PlotModel.Series}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" />
                <xctk:ColorPicker Width="30" ShowDropDownButton="False" SelectedColor="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Opacity="1" ShowRecentColors="True"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The ColorConverter XAML resource:

```
<local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"></local:ColorConverter>
```

And the C# code:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(OxyColor), typeof(Rect))]
class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{      
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is OxyColor)
        {
            var color = (OxyColor)value;
            if ((targetType == typeof(Color)) || (targetType == typeof(Color?)))
            {
                return color.ToColor();
            }

            if (targetType == typeof(Brush))
            {
                return color.ToBrush();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(OxyColor))
        {
            if (value is Color)
            {
                var color = (Color)value;
                return OxyColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            }

            if (value is SolidColorBrush)
            {
                var brush = (SolidColorBrush)value;
                Color color = brush.Color;
                return OxyColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is how I add new LineSeries dynamically:

```
LineSeries l = new LineSeries { LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, Title = title };
PlotModel.Series.Add(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the LineSeries instantiation works:

```
LineSeries l = new LineSeries { LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, Title = title, Color = PlotModel.DefaultColors[PlotModel.Series.Count] };
```

Is there another way? E.g. some kind of color property change event?

Comment: This answer fixes a problem where the selected line was inaccurately colored in the chart with checkable filter manually created, but I needed it to handle a bunch of lines (a.k.a. series).  There are 11 default colors in latest OxyPlot version, so use C# modulo operator.  So suggest:  
                int index = (PlotModel.Series.Count == 0) ? 0 : ((PlotModel.Series.Count - 1) % PlotModel.DefaultColors.Count); 
                LineSeries ls = new LineSeries() { Title = sq, Color = PlotModel.DefaultColors[index] };

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I had a similar requirement and achieved it by subclassing the LineSeries class (I had other reasons to do so, not just this) and overriding the base Color property using the 'new' keyword, then binding my view controls to the overridden property; and finally calling OnPropertyChanged or similar.
Something like this:

```
    public new OxyColor Color
    {
        get => base.Color;
        set
        {
            base.Color = value;
            // other logic if any
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
        }
    }
```